# Is there merit to adding flat properties additional to a duplicate nested

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

If I have a document designed like this:

```
  Question:
    properties:
      _id: string
      asker: User
      title: string
      description: string
      respondent: User
```

Is there performance merit to adding a duplicate property like this:

```
  Question:
    properties:
      _id: string
      asker_id: string
      asker: User
      title: string
      description: string
      respondent: User
```

Given that I need to query questions per asker?

Comment: How does the resulting BSON that gets stored in the db look like? What is the structure of `User`? Doesn't it already contain the `asker_id`?

Comment: @Thilo Yes it already contains the id. I'm wondering about this in terms of performance. What the difference in impact is of querying a property that is an extra level deep.

Comment: There is no difference. You only want to have a denormalized field if it is not already directly in the document (if it requires a calculation or lookup to another document).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the asker field is a single subdocument (i.e. not an array of users or something), I'm pretty sure the difference in access rates will be nil. I suspect you'd need to be doing thousands of inserts / updates / reads a second before even noticing any difference, and even then I doubt it: if you create an index on the field (which you should), the index doesn't care how deep the source data is. It hashes the field with a similar structure. Theoretically, there *may* be a slight increase in the index creation time in a super-complex document structure, but even that is unlikely, and regardless, happens only once, asynchronously, during the write. After that, read speeds shouldn't be effected.

My evidence for this isn't exact, but I have several high volume queries (i.e. can burst to several hundred queries or inserts per sec) on a specific table, where some of the queries are on a field 1-level deep, and one of the queries is on a field 4-levels deep, and I see no difference in access times or throughput rates (all fields are indexed).

Unless you're planning for very high loads, I wouldn't worry about it. I think it's a classic case of premature optimization which will complicate your code (now you need to make sure asker_id and asker.asker_id are the same) for no performance benefit. Just index the field and be done with it.

If you *are* planning for very high loads and large tables, then it should be pretty easy to profile and time your queries.

Comment: As you mention it, I also need to perform a search query which is an array of tags (string values). Is this performance ok or did you meet some problems with this?

Comment: In my experience, searching entire strings is fairly fast on Mongo (with indexing), but doing anything else e.g. regexp, substring matches, partial matches, etc. becomes slow pretty quickly. In my case, I needed to do substring matches on large numbers of documents, so I ended up using ElasticSearch for those queries.